# Delegate to class variable

Tags: ruby, delegation

I am using Ruby 2.6.5 and trying to use `def_delegator` to delegate to a class variable.

```rb
class A
  extend Forwardable

  @@classB = B.new
  def_delegator :@@classB, :method_name, :a_method_name
end
```

The is that when I try to do `A.new.a_method_name` I receive `NameError (uninitialized class variable @@classB in Object)`.  Not sure if I am making the call to `def_delegator` incorrectly or if I just need to break down and use ActiveSupport's `delegate`.

**UPDATE**

Based on acceptable answer my class definition looks like this:

```rb
class A
  extend Forwardable

  class << self
    attr_accessor :classB
  end
  self.classB = B.new

  def_delegator 'self.class.classB', :method_name, :a_method_name
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initiaize `@@classB` inside a class method and then refer to this class method:

```
class A
  extend Forwardable

  def self.b
    @@classB ||= B.new
  end
  def_delegator 'self.class.b', :method_name, :a_method_name
end
```

Comment: Ok, so basically I need a class level reader for the variable?

Comment: Yeah, seems like that.

Comment: Looks like it works.  Ended up doing `class << self; attr_accessor :classB; end` so I could do `self.classB = B.new`
This works well since this class is going to be inherited.